# Dist build of Google web app starter kit has different font than original

Tags: css, gulp, google-web-starter-kit

I am able to compile my web page using Google's Web App Starter Kit. However, upon running `gulp serve:dist`, my page is brought up with a different looking font than the default Roboto Condensed I expect. Instead, the font changes to what seemingly looks like default Roboto.

Terminal log does not indicate any errors and my dist folder indicates that I all my fonts are of Roboto Condensed. I've also tried testing on both chrome and safari but both show a different font:

```
 ~> gulp serve:dist
[21:26:17] Using gulpfile ~/dev/xxxx/gulpfile.js
[21:26:17] Starting 'clean'...
[21:26:17] Finished 'clean' after 33 ms
[21:26:17] Starting 'default'...
[21:26:17] Starting 'styles'...
[21:26:20] styles all files 92.91 kB
[21:26:20] Finished 'styles' after 2.6 s
[21:26:20] Starting 'jshint'...
[21:26:20] Starting 'html'...
[21:26:21] Starting 'images'...
[21:26:22] Starting 'fonts'...
[21:26:22] Starting 'copy'...
[21:26:22] Finished 'jshint' after 2.51 s
[21:26:23] html all files 51.2 kB
[21:26:23] Finished 'html' after 3.22 s
[21:26:24] copy all files 53.49 kB
[21:26:24] Finished 'copy' after 2.41 s
[21:26:25] fonts all files 1.09 MB
[21:26:25] Finished 'fonts' after 2.82 s
[21:26:25] images all files 27.96 MB
[21:26:25] Finished 'images' after 3.75 s
[21:26:25] Finished 'default' after 7.76 s
[21:26:25] Starting 'serve:dist'...
[21:26:25] Finished 'serve:dist' after 59 ms
[WSK] Local URL: http://localhost:3000
[WSK] External URL: http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3000
[WSK] Serving files from: dist
```

Anyone know how I can preserve the original Roboto Condensed font in the dist build? Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass?  Unless there is a Sass->CSS compilation issue, this is not a Sass problem.

Comment: I wasn't sure, I'm new to sass/gulp/gwsk.